# How to interpret this seemingly mysterious error?

Tags: altair

I was learning how to use altair, and the first thing I did was to reproduce a standard example straight from the official documentation. But there was a strange error I did not understand. The code is identical to the official example.

I am using altair 4.2.0, python 3.10.8 (and also 3.10.6) Here is the code run in a jupyter notebook (also tried with streamlit and encountered the same error):

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

iris = data.iris.url

chart1 = alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalLength:Q',
    y='petalWidth:Q',
    color='species:N'
).properties(
    height=300,
    width=300
)

chart2 = alt.Chart(iris).mark_bar().encode(
    x='count()',
    y=alt.Y('petalWidth:Q', bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=30)),
    color='species:N'
).properties(
    height=300,
    width=100
)

chart1 | chart2
```

Reference to the official example: https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/compound_charts.html
(the example about horizontal concatenation).

I expect to get a chart as showed in the official example but get the following error instead:

```
SchemaError: '#/definitions/TopLevelNormalizedHConcatSpec<GenericSpec>' is not a 'uri-reference'

Failed validating 'format' in metaschema['properties']['$ref']:
    {'format': 'uri-reference', 'type': 'string'}

On schema['$ref']:
    '#/definitions/TopLevelNormalizedHConcatSpec<GenericSpec>'
```

Can anyone test this to see if the error is indeed reproducible?

Comment: Works fine with Altair 4.2.0 and Python 3.10.6 and JupyterLab Version 3.4.8. If you want a place to work to learn without bothering to sort this out go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and press `launch binder`. When the session comes up, start a new notebook & then in i, run the following `%pip install altair` and then `%pip install vega_datasets`. (You can do both on separate lines in came cell.) Then the code you show will work. If it doesn't, be sure to restart the kernel  and try again. I didn't need to restart and it worked but YMMV. Sessions are temporary!

Comment: <continued> If you make anything useful save it back to your local system from the session. That way you can drag-and-drop in later to a fresh session and start where you left off.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check the JupyterLab version soon. Currently I am using altair charts in an streamlit app and am scratching my head to solve this issue.

Comment: Streamlit works with mybinder, too. (Search 'binder streamlit' and 'mybinder streamlit' in your favorite search engine to find some leads.) So you could still perhaps test things there to compare.

Comment: had similar issues with jlab 4.0.5 and altair 4.X, fixed by upgrading altair to new version (5.X)

Answer (score 0):

I turned out that something went wrong with my poetry config. I created a new environment and the problem was gone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).